# Find electric field given the magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Given the magnetic field as a vector, how do I find the electric field?

Comment: Please provide more explanations about your question. Is the magnetic field time dependent or not? Is it a magnetic field of an electromagnetic wave?

Comment: Hi user108605. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 1):

You must known the *impedance* of the medium. For the vacumm:

$$
\eta_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{\mu_0}{\varepsilon_0}}
$$

then, the relation between the fields:

$$
\vert\mathbf{H}\vert = \dfrac{\vert\mathbf{E}\vert}{\eta_0}
$$

in vacumm, of course.

Comment: [The impedance is the ratio of the *magnitudes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space) of the two vectors, so I don't believe that you can make the assertion your second equation makes.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Yes. I write the impedance here like a real variable. I tried to provide a guide, rather than an exact solution or an extremely long explanation.

Comment: The question specifically asks for vectors though, not magnitudes.

Comment: This is only true for EM waves in a vacuum.

Comment: @garyp : Yes. Maybe the next time I post a comment instead of an answer. Sorry, I just want to give a little help.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [Maxwell equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_equations).

Comment: That would tell me the curl of electric field, not electric field

Comment: You obviously can't find the electric field itself because the electric and magnetic fields are independent at each point.